# Error: _pickle.PicklingError: Could not pickle the task to send it to the workers. NotImplementedError: object proxy must define __reduce_ex__()

Tags: python, parallel-processing, joblib

I am using Python with joblib.

What could cause this error?

```
_pickle.PicklingError: Could not pickle the task to send it to the workers. 
...
NotImplementedError: object proxy must define __reduce_ex__()
```

Environment:

- Windows 10 x64 with WSL2
- Python 3.9 on Windows or Linux
- joblib

Answer (score 1):

In my particular case, the error was caused by adding the `@deprecated` property to a function:

```
from deprecated import deprecated # pip install Deprecated

@deprecated("Use function g instead.")
def f()
   ...
```

If the problem lies elsewhere, it is possible to do a binary search to find the function that cannot be pickled. Comment all the code out until the pickle error disappears, then gradually uncomment the code, half at a time, until it reappears.